# JQuery UI Diaglog to populate checkbox values to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a requirement that a user should select the checkbox values from a pop-up and click on submit on pop-up and the selected values should get displayed back to the parent page.

I was playing with some radio box values which I am able to push to the Parent window but struggling with checkbox values.

Here is what my pop-up looks like and my code is

```
    <p>Please Select a language:</p>
    <div id="myDialog" title="Select Language">
      <br /><br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="English" checked = "checked" /> English  <br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="French" /> French  <br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Norwagian" /> Norwagian  <br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Swedish" /> Swedish <br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Hindi" /> Hindi <br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Chinese" /> Chinese <br/>
      <br /><br />
      <label for="yes">Yes!</label><input type="radio" id="yes" value="yes" name="question" checked="checked"><br>
      <label for="no">No!</label> <input type="radio" id="no" value="no" name="question">
    </div>

    <p id="text">Selected Languages are: </p>
```

and my Jquery code that works for the selected radio button is as below

```
    $(function(){
      var execute = function(){
        var answer;
        $("input").each(function(){
          (this.checked == true) ? answer = $(this).val() : null;
        });
        $("<p>").text("You selected " + answer).appendTo($("body"));
        $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
      }
      var cancel = function() {
        $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
      }
      var dialogOpts = {
        buttons: {
          "Submit": execute,
           "Cancel": cancel
        }
      };
      $("#myDialog").dialog(dialogOpts);
    });
```

I'm trying to add the following JQuery code to display the selected checkbox values on the parent pages

```
    $('#myDialog').submit(function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();

      var arr = [];
      $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).val());
      });
      $(opener.document).contents().find("#text").text(arr.join(","));
      self.close(); 
    });
```

Please suggest as I'm still struggling to integrate the JQuery code of selected checkboxes to be displayed on the parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to iterate over each input and then store that in an array to append it to the body..

```
$(function () {
    var execute = function () {
        var answer = [];;
        $("input").each(function () {
            if (this.checked) answer.push(this.value);
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < answer.length ; i++)
            $("<p>").text("You selected " + answer[i]).appendTo($("body"));
    };
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4EK5x/)**

**Code**

```
$(function () {
    var execute = function () {
        var answer = [];;
        $("input").each(function () {
            if (this.checked) answer.push(this.value);
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++)
        $("<p>").text("You selected " + answer[i]).appendTo($("body"));
    };
    var cancel = function () {
        $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
    }
    var dialogOpts = {
        buttons: {
            "Submit": execute,
                "Cancel": cancel
        }
    };
    $("#myDialog").dialog(dialogOpts);
});
```

### **EDIT**

```
var cancel = function () {
    $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
}
var saveAndCancel = functionI() {
     execute();
     cancel();
}
var dialogOpts = {
    buttons: {
        "Submit": saveAndCancel ,
        "Cancel": cancel
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks , when I click on Submit , the dialogue box should get closed and the result needs to come as 
You Selected  English , French , Chinese etc 
Please suggest